# Allow others to use Op/Admin levers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Sorry if this is a simple question, but searching this forum and general googling wasn't yielding anything that seemed useful. Anyway, I am using the Yogcraft mod pack, and was wondering if there is some way to allow friends of mine to use things like levers that I place? It seems that since I am on the Op list, when I place a lever, they cannot use it. Anyway to fix that without making them Ops as well?

Only changes I have made were to Op the BuildCraft user so that the quarry can repair it's frame.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are these levers inside or outside the protected spawn area?

Comment: Ah, you know what? I never thought of that. I assumed are settlement began far away enough from the spawn protection zone. I guess we had beds so fast that we never noticed are deaths returning to that area.

Shrinking the spawn protection solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! For completeness, I'll make an answer to that effect.

Comment: Answer accepted.... oh, and i meant "OUR" settlement... and "OUR" deaths...  been a long day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're building within the spawn-protection area, so only ops can affect blocks (including levers and doors) within the range of the protection.

To fix this you can pull up stakes and move away from the spawn, rebuilding elsewhere. That might be a lot of work, though, so alternatively you can reduce the size of the spawn's protection radius in the server's configuration file. On an FTB server (which uses Forge, which changes the config options for spawn protection compared to the vanilla server), you want to look for or add this line:

```
spawn-protection-size=70
```

<sup>*(That line is from my own server on which I've increased the protection area. The default is smaller; 40, I believe.)*</sup>

Once you find the line, reduce it down as necessary until the stuff you want accessible to your players can be used by non-ops. (To test this, I find it's convenient to de-op myself and work outward from the spawn centre until I find blocks I can break, then re-op myself using the server console.)

Yet another alternative is to disable spawn protection entirely by setting this line to `false`:

```
spawn-protection=true
```

Shrinking or disabling spawn protection is only recommended on private servers where you trust your players, of course!